# Use Overpass API to output different tag counts as CSV

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, count, overpass-turbo

I want to create CSV data with different OpenStreetMap tag counts for selected cities using Overpass API. Unfortunately, the ["Counting Objects" section of the Overpass API Documentation](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/counting/index.html) is still empty. Also, this [count function documentation](https://www.renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/OpenStreetMap/API/Overpass/functions/count) only shows how to count nodes, ways, relations or a combination for **a single tag query**.

How can an **output containing several columns for different tag counts** be achieved?

I found this helpful [example for counting pharmacies](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Count_Pharmacies_per_County_(updated_0.7.54)).

And this is what my query currently looks like:

```
// Define fields for CSV output
[out:csv(name, "node[railway=station]", "node[highway=bus_stop]")];

// Select area
{{geocodeArea:München}}->.munich;

// Query stations and bus stops
node(area.munich)[railway=station];
//node(area.regio)[highway=bus_stop]; // How can this count be added separately?

// Count stations
make count name = munich.set(t["name"]),
           "node[railway=station]" = count(nodes);

// Output CSV
out;
```

If I uncomment the `node(area.regio)[highway=bus_stop]`... line, only the bus stop count is contained in the output, but should appear in an additional column next to the railway station count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each query part must be saved as a variable that then has to be used as a prefix for `count()`. Then, a separate `out;` is necessary for each CSV row.

```
// Define fields for CSV output
[out:csv(feature, number)];

// Select area
{{geocodeArea:München}}->.munich; 

// Query stations and bus stops
node(area.munich)[railway=station]->.railstations;
node(area.munich)[highway=bus_stop]->.busstops; 

// Count railway stations
make count feature = "railway=station",
           number = railstations.count(nodes);

// Output first CSV row
out;

// Count bus stops
make count feature = "highway=bus_stop",
           number = busstops.count(nodes);

// Output second CSV row
out;
```

Here's another example that creates CSV data for three different cities and uses a `foreach` loop:

```
// Define fields for CSV output
[out:csv(city, "railway stations", "bus stops")];

// Select area
(
  {{geocodeArea:Berlin}};
  {{geocodeArea:Hamburg}};
  {{geocodeArea:München}};
);

// Query stations and bus stops for each city
foreach->.c(
  node(area.c)[railway=station]->.railwaystations;
  node(area.c)[highway=bus_stop]->.busstops;
  
  // Count stations
  make count city = c.set(t["name"]),
           "railway stations" = railwaystations.count(nodes),
           "bus stops" = busstops.count(nodes);
  
  // Output CSV row
  out; 
);
```

[See the original answer in the OSM community forum](https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/use-overpass-api-to-output-different-tag-counts-as-csv/106139/2).